# populating parts of a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a covariance matrix of stock returns, say 100 by 100.

There are two stocks where the values are nan. So currently rows 95 & 96 are nan across & columns 95 & 96 are all nan's as well. I want to populate these nans with the mean value of the column.

So I have written the code below.

```
# get the mean of each column
col_mean = np.nanmean(cov_tot, axis=1)

# indexing to find which columns are nan's
idx_miss = np.isnan(cov_tot[:, 0])

# now populate the missing rows & columns
cov_tot[idx_miss, :] = col_mean
cov_tot[:, idx_miss] = col_mean
```

The line below works fine.

> cov_tot[idx_miss, :] = col_mean

The last line below doesn't work & I'm unsure why.

> cov_tot[:, idx_miss] = col_mean

The error message is,

> *** ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (100,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,100)

Not sure why one line works & the other doesn't? I tried using transpose but that made no difference either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
means = np.nanmean(arr1, axis=0)
arr2 = np.where(np.isnan(arr1), means, arr1) #replace row nans with colwise means
arr3 = np.where(np.isnan(arr2), arr2.T, arr2) #replicate to columns with nans
arr4 = np.where(np.isnan(arr3),np.nanmean(np.diagonal(arr3)),arr3) #replace diagonal nan by mean of diagonal
```

`arr2` first have column-wise means replacing nans in ROWS. next `arr3` takes the means and replaces the COLUMNS with nans. Last, `arr4` take the diagonal mean and replaces nans on DIAGONAL with it.

Comment: thanks for the post. When I try it though it doesn't work for my example. The reason I believe is in the example above the 3rd row is all nan so the 3rd column should also be all nan as the matrix is a covariance matrix

Comment: Ah ok, so what do you want to replace it with? the column and row?

Comment: so column 3 would have the same values as row 3 but transposed

Comment: That would still leave 1 nan value in the center.. (diagonal value for the rows with nans)

Comment: `arr2` first have column wise means replacing nans in ROWS. next `arr3` takes the means and replaces the COLUMNS with nans. Last, `arr4` take the diagonal mean and replaces nans on DIAGONAL with it.